# 2D dot product on two 3D matrix along an aixs

Tags: numpy, matrix-multiplication

Given two matrixes A and B with dimension of (x,y,z) and (y,x,z) respectively, how to dot product on the first two dimension of the two matrices? The result should have dimension of (x,x,z).

Thanks!

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: Yes!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) with literally the same string expression -

```
np.einsum('xyz,yiz->xiz',a,b) # a,b are input arrays
```

Note that we have used `yiz` as the string notation for the second array and not `yxz`, as that `i` is supposed to be a new dimension in the output array and is not to be aligned with the first axis of the first array for which we have already assigned `x`. The dimensions that are to be aligned are given the same string notation.